# Python: How to get HTTP header using RAW_Sockets

Tags: python-3.x, http-headers, packet-sniffers

I'm beginner in Python and I would like to build simple port sniffer.
For this purpose I'm using code from this site, as example: [Simple packege snffer using python](http://www.bitforestinfo.com/2017/01/how-to-write-simple-packet-sniffer.html)
And I would like to unpack bites from socket to exctract http header, using function struct.unpack()

What format of string should I use in unpack HTTP header, (e.g '!BBH', "!BBHHHBBH4s4s",'!HHLLBBHHH')

Answer (score 3):

the HTTP header is not fixed-length, so you'll need to parse it other way, for example:

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def parse_http(data):
        lines = data.split(b'\r\n')
        if len(lines) < 1:
            log.error('Invalid http header: %s', lines)
            return
        request = lines[0]
        header = {}
        rest = []
        in_header = True

        for line in lines[1:]:
            if line == b'':
                in_header = False
                continue
            if in_header:
                try:
                    key, val = line.split(b': ')
                except ValueError:
                    log.error('Invalid header line: %s', line)
                    continue
                header[key] = val
            else:
                rest.append(line)

        return request, header, b'\r\n'.join(rest)
```

In order to detect a HTTP packet, you could check if the payload starts with POST, GET, HTTP ... etc